# Icinga2 Python Notification Script

Tags: python, monitoring, icinga2

I am working on our Icinga2 monitoring server and I would like to do a little customization with our notifications. So, for example our workday is from 08:00 - 17:00 M-F, for any notifications during that time period need to go "group1". Anything, that is outside of that M-F 8:00 - 17:00 period need to go to "group2". Also, within group 1 between 08:00 - 17:00 there is different people that notifications need to go to. I am trying to write this script in python and I am just unsure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use [Timeperiod](https://icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/08-advanced-topics/#time-periods), Notification, User, and UserGroup objets instead.

A custom notification script is not needed in a such case.

Comment: Each week the schedule that we want to use to send notifications changes and is updated. So, we want this script to pull the schedule from our internal website and push them into Icinga and just always send the notification to the right person with out any manual work.